# How do I generate server.js during the SSR build?

Tags: angular-universal, iisnode

I'm not sure of the exact steps I took but at one time I created a new project and was able to compile the applicaiton and a server.js file was generated int he root of the dist folder. I'm unable to reproduce that in my current project though. I've been unsuccessful and getting the application to serve in IIS without this file.

```
npm run build:ssr
```

Only generates the following files:

```
.\dist 
.\server  
.\server\main.js 
.\browser  
.\browser\...
```

**Should I be using a different command to generate the SSR build?**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the project version. For angular 8 and below, the default angular universal setup will generate a `dist\server\main.js` file.

For angular 9+, the file will be `dist\<project>\server\server.js`